# Which of the tags [canonical], [rel-canonical] and [canonical-url] is the canonical one?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retagging

Of the three, only [canonical-url](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-url) has any usage guidance or tag wiki. The other two ([canonical](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical) and [rel-canonical](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rel-canonical)) are bare. Glancing over the questions in each tag, there does not appear to be any meaningful distinction in usage. Should these tags be merged?

Comment: So you're asking which is the canonical canonical tag?

Comment: How very meta, and very Meta.

Answer (score 5):

[rel-canonical](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rel-canonical) is a specific type of canonical implementation.  It uses a meta tag.  The other implementation for canonical URLs is 301 redirects.  I'd keep [rel-canonical](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rel-canonical) separate from the others.   I have written a [tag wiki for rel-canonical](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/rel-canonical/info).

[canonical](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical) and [canonical-url](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-url) are probably similar enough to merge on this site.   There could be canonical things other than URLs, but I'd expect that 99.9% of the usage of [canonical](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical) refers to URLs.   Because of that, I would prefer [canonical-url](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-url) to be the canonical of the two.

---

**EDIT**:  The proposed merge of "canonical" and "canonical-url" has now been completed:

[image]